# decompose.graph function in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a piece of code below. I am not able to understand how exactly "decompose.graph" works. In the below code, I want to see what is there in "comps". but it shows as some structure of lists, which I m not able to understand.

Also which function can I use to see the graphical representation of "comps"(I tried plot but it is not working)

```
gr<-graph(c(1,2,1,3,1,4,2,3,2,4,3,4),directed=FALSE)

cl<-cliques(gr,min=2,max=2)

  edges <- c()
  for (i in seq_along(cl)) {
    for (j in seq_along(cl)) {
      if ( length(unique(c(cl[[i]], cl[[j]]))) == 3 ) {
        edges <- c(edges, c(i,j))
      }
    }
  }

  plot(clq.graph) <- simplify(graph(edges))
  V(clq.graph)$name <- seq_len(vcount(clq.graph))
  comps <- decompose.graph(clq.graph)

  lapply(comps, function(x) {
    unique(unlist(cl[ V(x)$name ]))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if you want to see the code behind a function in R, you can type the function name at the command and press Enter. This will give you an overview of the code. For example:

```
> decompose
```

will give you:

```
function (x, type = c("additive", "multiplicative"), filter = NULL) 
{
    type <- match.arg(type)
    l <- length(x)
    f <- frequency(x)
    if (f <= 1 || length(na.omit(x)) < 2 * f) 
        stop("time series has no or less than 2 periods")
    if (is.null(filter)) 
        filter <- if (!f%%2) 
            c(0.5, rep(1, f - 1), 0.5)/f
        else rep(1, f)/f
    trend <- filter(x, filter)
    season <- if (type == "additive") 
        x - trend
    else x/trend
    periods <- l%/%f
    index <- seq(1L, l, by = f) - 1
    figure <- numeric(f)
    for (i in 1L:f) figure[i] <- mean(season[index + i], na.rm = TRUE)
    figure <- if (type == "additive") 
        figure - mean(figure)
    else figure/mean(figure)
    seasonal <- ts(rep(figure, periods + 1)[seq_len(l)], start = start(x), 
        frequency = f)
    structure(list(x = x, seasonal = seasonal, trend = trend, 
        random = if (type == "additive") x - seasonal - trend else x/seasonal/trend, 
        figure = figure, type = type), class = "decomposed.ts")
}
<environment: namespace:forecast>
```

I tried the same for decompose.graph but I don't seem to have the function available. Is this isn a special library? I also have some challenges to execute your code as also the function `cliques` doesn't seem to be available; including what library you are working with would help.

Comment: Ya i forgot to mention that these codes are available in the package, "igraph". I know how to see the source code. I just want a brief explanation of that function.  I could not understand what is there in R help. So please let me know if you get any more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code, you will know what's the function of `decompose.graph()`

```
library(igraph)
g <- sample_gnp(10, 1/10)
plot(g)
components <- decompose.graph(g, min.vertices=2)
par(mfrow = c(1, length(components)))
for (i in 1:length(components)){
  plot(components[[i]])
}
```

First you will get a graph like this:
[Graph created by `sample_gnp()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANGyK.png)
After `decompose.graph()` you will get subgraphs like this:
[Subgraph after `decompose.graph()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC2Vy.png)